# Validate Gherkin Feature File

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, cucumber, gherkin

I used IntelliJ to write Cucumber feature files i.e., *.feature files and corresponding step definition files in Java within the IDE. The user experience is great and IDE opens up its IntelliSense showing all valid options for which the step definitions exist. If I write a new step in a scenario or a step that has no corresponding step definition exist already in the Java file, it highlights the step with different colour and similarly if regex don't match. I get informed by this highlighting that something has to be written for this step in Java file or the step is wrong and will not execute.

I need the same functionality on a non developer machine i.e., on a Business Analyst or Product owner machine, where there is no IDE installed but just an editor like Notepad++. I know about the Notepad++ plug-in for Gherkin but it doesn't highlight the step for which step definition is missing in the *.java step definition file. Please suggest any editor or free IDE that has similar plug-in available.

Thanks,
Shany

Comment: This might be a use case for Cucumber Pro. My suggestion is to contact the core Cucumber team ans ask them. I am not aware of any open source options, except for development environments.

Comment: HonestCode.io is a service designed for Product owners to write acceptance tests online in Gherkin, it helps you showing already defined steps, but don't match them with *.java step definition file (that's more a developer task), so maybe isn't what you are looking for. 
Disclaimer: I work for HonestCode

Comment: @Troglo would disagree this is a developer task, the scenario writer needs to understand what steps they have to work with otherwise a developer will end up having to write customer steps for each scenario, you should add this feature to your product!

Comment: @nbransby I mean that *.java files doesn't have much value for Scenario writers, they must have already the complete definition in the Gherkin Scenario and Steps so don´t need to check the code implementation. In BDD/ATDD it´ll be inusual to have step definitions in the Java files before having it used in Scenarios. Of course, all Gherkin Scenario steps are available and autocompleted in the tool to help Scenario writers.

Answer (score -1):

In case you use JIRA to manage your stories then you can use a JIRA plugin which has Auto-complete, parameter highlight functionality. There are other similar plugins you can browse.